# index.css doesn't apply itself even though it is present

Tags: html, css

I am having a really odd issue where my index.css is not automatically applying itself to my webpage. This works on my local machine but when I push this code out to my django server, it doesn't apply. I know this should work because I can see that index.css file inside of the "Sources" pane in the chrome dev tools. I also know that it is linking to the file because if I right click the rhef in my html on chrome dev tools, it brings me to the css file with my code in it. Another odd thing is none of the code applies itself but if I edit the index.css in any way on chrome dev tools, it applies my css and works perfectly but only after I edit it. How come it isn't applying itself when I open the page?

Here is my element that calls the index.css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/index.css">
```

Comment: There is some cache involved probably, either on your browser or on the server.

Comment: @ITgoldman I have tried clearing cache, incognito, firefox, chrome, another computer, and my phone and it is all the same issue. How do I clear the cache on the server?

Comment: First of all let me rephrase my statement to "it might be". Secondly maybe there is different folder for working css and production (dist) css

Comment: I just don't understand how the file is there and is the one that the webpage points to but it doesn't apply. As soon as I do anything to the index.css, like an enter, space, backspace, the css applies to the page.